# Unsupported major.minor version when doing GWT compile in eclipse

Tags: gwt, gwt-compiler, unsupported-class-version

So I'm getting the following exception:
I know that `major.minor version` exceptions come when you are compiling with an old jdk and running with a newer one but i'm just doing GWT compile. Can anyone shed some light on this:

```
Compiling module com.domkee.entities.Entities
[ERROR] Unexpected internal compiler error
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/domkee/entities/client/annontations/Table : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.TypeOracleMediator.getAnnotationClass(TypeOracleMediator.java:575)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.TypeOracleMediator.resolveAnnotation(TypeOracleMediator.java:643)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.TypeOracleMediator.resolveAnnotations(TypeOracleMediator.java:663)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.TypeOracleMediator.resolveClass(TypeOracleMediator.java:809)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.TypeOracleMediator.addNewTypes(TypeOracleMediator.java:439)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.TypeOracleMediatorFromSource.addNewUnits(TypeOracleMediatorFromSource.java:52)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationState.assimilateUnits(CompilationState.java:164)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationState.<init>(CompilationState.java:82)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.doBuildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:450)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.buildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:370)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDef.getCompilationState(ModuleDef.java:360)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:252)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:233)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:145)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:232)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:198)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:170)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:88)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:82)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:177)
```

Comment: I have seen this error occur if your environment variable JAVA_HOME is set different to what your ECLIPSE defalt JRE setting is set to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't figure the problem, but  I figured the solution:

1. Close eclipse
2. I uninstalled all the jdks (Apparently I had like 4)
3. I installed a new one (java 1.6)
4. Run eclipse
5. set the compiler in window->preferences->java->compiler
6. Projects can have an individually set compilers that is not the default workspace compiler
   so go through each project and right->click ->preferences -> java compiler
   and set a 1.6 compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with these exceptions but make sure you setup the Java compiler to target Java 1.6 (and specifically not 1.7), and that you use Java 1.6 or newer to run the GWT compiler.

Comment: We are compiling with Java 7 for both server and gwt client.

Comment: I do too. I was talking about compiling *for* Java 6, not necessarily *with* Java 6.